# What advantages does Windows Embedded Enterprise give you?

Tags: windows, windows-embedded

My company has built a machine that measures wedge and roundness of lenses by reading and interacting with very precise indicators, motors, and a switch panel. The interface for the machine is a WPF application and it runs on Windows Vista on a normal PC bought from the store.

I've never worked with Windows Embedded, but it sounds to me like it's intended for this type of system. My question is, what does it buy me? If I were to run this on Windows Embedded Enterprise (Vista) what benefits do I get?

Do I get more control of the load, login, and all that? Can I make it more seamless where it doesn't really feel just like a normal application running full screen?

Is it something I should look into more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Embedded Enterprise is a different SKU but exactly the same OS. You will not get any better control of the load, login, etc.

If you want to do such things, you need to consider Windows Embedded *Standard*. The actual available version is Windows Embedded Strandard 2009 and is based on Windows XP Pro (which can still run .Net apps) and next release, Windows Embedded Standard 7, will be based on Windows 7. These OS are componentized versions, meaning you start from scratch and agregate the components of the OS you need and just these ones.

More details can be found at: [WindowsEmbedded.com](http://WindowsEmbedded.com)

Comment: -1, question is about specific features of WE Enterprise against mainstream Windows

Answer (score 2):

[From Wikipedia,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Embedded) this statement tells the whole story:

> Windows Embedded Enterprise brand of Windows Embedded Operating
>   Systems consist of Windows XP for Embedded Systems and Windows Vista
>   for Embedded Systems, which are the same versions of the OSes as are
>   available in retail but are licensed exclusively for use in embedded
>   devices. They are available for both x86 as well as x86-64 (x64)
>   processors.

Further confusing this branding decision, the only versions of Windows Vista available under Windows Embedded Enterprise [are Business and Ultimate](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/downloads/download-windows-embedded-enterprise.aspx). In non-terse [Microspeak](http://cinepad.com/mslex.htm), *Windows Vista Business for Embedded Systems* and *Windows Vista Ultimate for Embedded Systems* are both *Windows Embedded Enterprise* products.

Since you're effectively getting the exact same OS, the only benefits to choosing this product over any other version of Windows Vista are your desired licensing. [Here's the comparison matrix of Vista products by edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista_editions#Comparison_chart), and as before, you're looking at the columns labeled *Business* and *Ultimate*, **not** *Enterprise*.

For versions of Windows that have actual tangible benefits in the form of smaller kernels and increased robustness for embedded systems, consider [the remaining editions listed on this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Embedded).

---

For the benefit of current users at the time of this writing, this branding decision extends to Windows 7.

Here's [the comparison matrix detailing the benefits of *Windows 7 Professional SP1* and *Ultimate for Embedded Systems*](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/evaluate/windows-embedded-enterprise.aspx). As before, Microsoft's product marketing is somewhat  misleading:

> These products are fully functional versions of Microsoft’s desktop
>   operating system intended for use in an embedded solution consisting
>   of purpose-built hardware and application software.

[Here's the comparison of editions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_editions#Comparison_chart). You're looking at the columns labeled *Professional* and *Ultimate* again for the features you'll receive with either product offering.

For embedded solutions in Windows 7 that actually involve a customized version of the OS, consider [Windows Embedded Standard](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/evaluate/windows-embedded-standard-7.aspx) or [Windows Thin PC](http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/software-assurance/windows-thin-pc.aspx) for slimming down aspects of the OS. Microsoft's documentation is far better than I can tractably fit in an answer here.

Comment: It seems strange to focus on Vista, even if the question is 3 years ago asks about this edition. I suppose it won't hurt anyone to focus on 7 instead

Comment: @CharlesB Vista was integral to the original question. If a comparison for 7 is preferred, it may be better as its own question, due to the intentions of the original author.

Comment: Sure but your answer will be more useful to others if you extend to 7. No interest in asking the same question for 7, as nothing has changed in between. Anyway thanks for the post!

Comment: @CharlesB That's entirely reasonable. I'll extend it. :)

Comment: As an aside, Microsoft really needs to get on top of its branding decisions. Its hard to stifle a laugh when their product namespace is so conflicted, at least in English-speaking nations.